# Unlist documents by name in Dart Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application like this:

[image]

All list elements here come from Firestore. The Firestore build is as follows:

[image]

One of the documents is called "*bilgiler*". In this document, I keep the person's information. And I don't want to show it in the list. The code is looking for the title value from the items in the list. And since there is no title value in this `title` document, it is passed to the list as `null`.

I don't want to show that document in the list in the application if the document name is "bilgiler". How can I do that?

Codes:

```
  Container(
    height: 500,
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: InkWell(
                      child: Icon(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["done"] == true ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.radio_button_unchecked, color: Colors.green, size: 28,),
                      onTap: () {
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].id).update({
                          "done": !snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["done"],
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    title: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["done"] == true ? Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["title"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),) : Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["title"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)),
                    trailing: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.label_important, size: 28, color: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["important"] == true ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].id).update({
                              "important": !snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["important"],
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10,),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 28,),
                          onTap: () {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].id).delete();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error');
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
  ),
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If the title is same for all `bilgiler` then you can do a simple comparison and show an sized box where title is `bilgiler`

```
return Container(child: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['title']=='bilgiler' ?? false ? SizedBox(): InkWell(
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: InkWell(
```

Comment: @griffinler Thanks for the response. The document named "bilgiler" in Firestore documents has no title value. So this document will never appear. You misunderstood.